# Is the opaque UIView which is shown when a UISearchDisplayController is set active an editable property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I set a `UISearchDisplayController` as active with `[mySearchDisplayController setActive:YES];` a semi-transparent black UIView is animated on screen from the frame `(0, 0, 0. 0)`.  Is this UIView a property and if so what is its name?  I'm animating the `UISearchBar` associated with the `UISearchDisplayController` and need to change the origin for the `UIView` animation.